# How do I call a vba function within the same module?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote 3 functions

`CellAbove` takes a cell and returns the cell above

`CellAboveValueV1` takes a cell and returns the string value of the above cell using `.offset(-1,0)`

`CellAboveValueV2` uses `CellAbove` to return the string value of the above cell

Here's what my code looks like:

```
Function CellAbove(r As Range) As Range
    CellAbove = r.Offset(-1, 0)
End Function

Function CellAboveValueV1(r As Range) As String
    CellAboveValueV1 = r.Offset(-1, 0).Value
End Function

Function CellAboveValueV2(r As Range) As String
    CellAboveValueV2 = CellAbove(r).Value
End Function
```

But when I test this functions with the excel data below, `v1` function works, but the `v2` function doesn't. What am I missing?

```
data  | V1(data) | v2(data)
----------------------------
row 1 | data     | #VALUE!
row 2 | row 1    | #VALUE!
row 3 | row 2    | #VALUE!
```

Comment: `Set CellAbove = r.Offset(-1, 0)`, missing a `Set`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks!

Comment: One thing to be aware.  The functions are not volatile and since they are anchored on the cell below the one it returns, it will not recalc unless the cell to which it refers(the one passed to the function) changes.  It will not recalc if the cell above changes as the function is not pointed at it.